# How to select most recent value pulled using wb api

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I currently have this:

```
                        industry    population
            country date        
Australia   2017-01-01  NaN         NaN
            2016-01-01  24.327571   18.898304
            2015-01-01  25.396251   18.835267
            2014-01-01  27.277007   18.834835
United States2017-01-01 NaN         NaN
            2016-01-01  NaN         19.028231
            2015-01-01  20.027274   19.212860
            2014-01-01  20.867359   19.379071
```

And would like to select the most recent values for each country and column so that the most recent non null value is returned:

```
                        industry    population

Australia              24.327571    18.898304

United States           20.027274   19.028231
```

I know that I can groupby the country index, which is part of a multilevel industry consisting of the country and date but after that I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is use custom function with `bfill` and `iloc` for select first row in group:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.bfill().iloc[0])
print (df)
                industry  population
country                             
Australia      24.327571   18.898304
United States  20.027274   19.028231
```

---

Solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for automatically removing first `NaN`s, but in future this behaviour [should be changed - it is bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427):

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).first()
print (df)
                industry  population
country                             
Australia      24.327571   18.898304
United States  20.027274   19.028231
```

Comment: Is there any way to add a column that shows the year of the data as well? and in the case where the year is different for the same country to return the oldest year of the data in the new data frame? So for Australia, that would be 2016 and US that would be 2015

Comment: I am offline now, on phone only, so the best is create new question. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657932/used-groupby-to-select-most-recent-data-want-to-append-a-column-that-returns-th

Comment: OOO, give me some time ;)

Comment: `in the case where the year is different for the same country` it means `max` year for rows with no `NaN`s ?