# Used groupby to select most recent data, want to append a column that returns the date of the data

Tags: python, group-by, pandas-groupby

I originally had a dataframe that looked like this:

```
                                  industry    population %of rural land
        country       date        
        Australia     2017-01-01  NaN         NaN        NaN
                      2016-01-01  24.327571   18.898304  12
                      2015-01-01  25.396251   18.835267  12
                      2014-01-01  27.277007   18.834835  13
        United States 2017-01-01  NaN         NaN        NaN
                      2016-01-01  NaN         19.028231  NaN
                      2015-01-01  20.027274   19.212860  NaN
                      2014-01-01  20.867359   19.379071  NaN
```

I applied the following code which pulled the most recent data for each of the columns for each of the countries and resulted in the following dataset:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).first()

               industry  population  %of rural land
country                             
Australia      24.327571   18.898304 12
United States  20.027274   19.028231 NaN
```

Is there any way to add a column that shows the year of the data as well? and in the case where the year is different for the same country to return the oldest year of the data in the new data frame? So for Australia, that would be 2016 and US that would be 2015. Ideally, the dataframe would look like this:

```
               year      industry  population  %of rural land
country                             
Australia      2016      24.327571   18.898304 12
United States  2015      20.027274   19.028231 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need for `first` year of non `NaN`s rows create helper `Series` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then :

```
s = df.dropna().reset_index(level=1)['date'].dt.year.groupby(level=0).first()
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).first()
df1.insert(0, 'year', df1.rename(s).index)
#alternative
#df1.insert(0, 'year', df1.index.to_series().map(s))
print (df1)
               year   industry  population
country                                   
Australia      2016  24.327571   18.898304
United States  2015  20.027274   19.028231
```

Another solution with add `NaNs` to `date` column and last get years by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df1 = (df.reset_index(level=1)
        .assign(date=lambda x: x['date'].where(df.notnull().all(1).values))
        .groupby(level=0).first()
        .assign(date=lambda x: x['date'].dt.year)
        .rename(columns={'date':'year'}))
print (df1)
               year   industry  population
country                                   
Australia      2016  24.327571   18.898304
United States  2015  20.027274   19.028231
```

EDIT:

```
def f(x):
    #check NaNs
    m = x.isnull()
    #remove all NaNs columns 
    m = m.loc[:, ~m.all()]
    #first index value of non NaNs rows
    m = m[~m.any(1)].index[0][1].year
    return (m)

s = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f)
print (s)
country
Australia        2016
United States    2015
dtype: int64

df1 = df.groupby(level=0).first()
df1.insert(0, 'year', df1.rename(s).index)
#alternative
#df1.insert(0, 'year', df1.index.to_series().map(s))
print (df1)
               year   industry  population  %of rural land
country                                                   
Australia      2016  24.327571   18.898304            12.0
United States  2015  20.027274   19.028231             NaN
```

Comment: The first solution returns the name of the country when is the year is NaN but the second solution gives NaN when it is NaN, which is what I want! The years are coming up as floats (2016.00000). Where in the second solution can I change that ?

Comment: Maybe some problem with pandas versions, do you use last `0.21.0` ?

Comment: i have 0.21.0 now. also, i am getting this error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Then is simplier first solution, use `s = pd.to_datetime(df.dropna().reset_index(level=1)['date']).dt.year.groupby(level=0).first()`

Comment: and for second need change `.assign(date=lambda x: x['date'].dt.year)` to `.assign(date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.year)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160546/discussion-between-susan-chen-and-jezrael).

Comment: There is some problem?

Comment: yes, i think that "NaN" is returned for the year when a country has NaN as the result of some of the variables. so for example, for australia, is industry is NaN and population is not, the year for australia will be 'NaN'

Comment: So with sample data you get wrong output? Or better question, do you need top year by countries after removing all rows with NaNs? Or logic is different?

Comment: I pull data for each country for the last five years, and for a few of the variables, there is no data for the last five years, so the most recent value for those variables is "NaN". That is ok with me, but it seems like if a country has a few "NaN"s the above code will return "NaN". I want the code to still look at years of the available variables.

Comment: Not sure if understand.If all values are NaNs, for example sample in question with all NaNs what is desired output? I gues for columns NaNs and for yers top, first years per countries?

Comment: I edited the dataframes in the question above to give you an example of what I mean. If I apply the code that you give me, the year in the last dataframe is NaN because '%of rural land" is NaN. How can I disregard the NaN values and return the year for the available data for each country?

Comment: So is possible remove all nans columns first and then apply my solution? Then use first step `df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')`, check also [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: Sorry that was a bad example. I changed it so you might know what I mean. I can't drop the column because it might not be null for all countries.

Comment: This error is returned: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: I try test it and I cannot simulate youe error. Are data confidental? If not, is possible send me csv to my email in my profile?